# Fixing could not create leading directories ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

```
gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.0.2 (ea19241)
Using Shell executor...
Running on ip-...
Cloning repository...
fatal: could not create leading directories of '/home/gitlab_ci/builds/aac52f34/0/user/app': Permission denied

ERROR: Build failed with: exit status 1
```

is there anyway i could make this work ?

[my-issue-in-bitnami](https://community.bitnami.com/t/hi-im-having-problem-with-ci-its-always-pending/42359/6)

Comment: Have you installed the runner via package?

Comment: yes , via bitnami gitlab they have documentation there , I also have backup

Comment: Check under what user the runner is working on.

Comment: I thought gitlab ci runner is run by root, how do i check for user using gitlab ci runner?

Comment: could you please post the output of the following two commands? `ls -la /home/gitlab_ci/builds/aac52f34/0/user/app` and `id`

Answer (score 1):

Do a `sudo (mkdir -P /home/gitlab_ci/builds/ && chmod 777 /home/gitlab_ci/builds/)`

You have a permissions problem best solved by making a directory permissive, verifying the problem going away, and then refining your solution as necessary.

If the system itself is shared with untrusted people, you can

- create a group with the github robot and trusted people,
- change the group ownership of the directory (chgrp)
- make the directory group writable but publically not.

Comment: sorry for the late response, I already fixed the problem, there was a script I had to change because there was a problem running the script for `gitlab-multi-runner` and actually the problem was not the permission.

Comment: thanks for the answer anyway, some people might have the same problem like me and and your answer maybe is correct.